# How to configure custom serializer for all custom types in Hazelcast

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

Would it be correct to set custom serializer for `Object.class`:

```
new Config().getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(
  new SerializerConfig()
    .setImplementation(new MySerializer())
    .setTypeClass(Object.class)
);
```

or should I use some wrapper class when puting or geting some value to/from Hazelcast:

```
new Config().getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(
  new SerializerConfig()
    .setImplementation(new MySerializer())
    .setTypeClass(MyWrapper.class)
);

hazelcast.getMap("some map").put("my key", new MyWrapper(anyCustomValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Every java class extends Object.

Storing object type can be a solution to store multiple class types.
But,

If you need to store different class types in your `hazelcast map`, I can suggest you to use a wrapper object to cover them and cover that object serialization requirement in your single serialization class. Obviously, this way gives you more control of your objects to manage like get and set. Otherwise, you may need a couple of implementation to cover types of an object to cast which one is. And managing this situation can be painful in the future instead of using a single wrapper object.